# Book Recommendations for Integral Geometry, focusing on Crofton's Formula and Applications

Tags: probability-theory, differential-geometry, book-recommendation

I am seeking recommendations for books or resources that provide an engaging introduction to integral geometry, with a particular interest in Crofton's formula and its various proofs. I am looking for both classical texts that lay the foundational aspects and modern works that delve into applications across different fields. A balance between theoretical depth and practical insights would be ideal. Any suggestions that cover the historical evolution of these concepts alongside contemporary developments would also be highly appreciated.

Comment: The standard classical source is [Santaló](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/integral-geometry-and-geometric-probability/C184465D9420B97C2FBF312E58245230).

Comment: Another beautiful book on this is the one by Klain and Rota. https://faculty.uml.edu//dklain/blurb.html